# Android - display images in assets sub-folder in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

In my app I have a bunch of HTML pages that I want to display in WebView's. The HTML references images that are also stored in the app.

Everything works fine if I put the HTML file and the images into the root of the 'assets' folder and load the HTML like:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.faqs_html);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.htm");
```

And where the HTML just refers to the image like:

`<img src="logo.png" width="145" height="23" />`

So I've got a fallback, but I'd prefer to have the images in a sub-folder inside the assets folder; but when I do that I can't seem to get the image to display in the WebView. I've tried  the obvious `<img src="images/logo.png" width="145" height="23" />` and some other attempts, but it's not working. Thanks!

Comment: use following file:///android_asset/

eg src="ifile:///android_asset/"+"images/logo.png" name width="145" height="23" />

Answer (score 1):

There might be some corrections in the link you are providing. Recently I developed an app in which the images are loaded from sub-folders and also from other directories.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Which 'link' are you referring to?

Comment: link to index.html or links to the images in that file. U still facing the same problem?